# date insertion in database using servlet

Tags: html, servlets, datepicker

I am trying to insert date in the oracle daatbase using html5 datepicker but ,the date format which was inserted was different  from the date format given in the input.Pikcing date randomly.
Example: mm/dd/yyyy  12/10/2014 (input date)
         the date inserted in the database was  07-jul-2015

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my servlet code:

```
public class DateServlet extends GenericServlet
{
 Connection con = null;
 PreparedStatement ps = null;

 public void init(ServletConfig config)
 {
    try
    {
        con = DatabaseCon.dbConnection();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException    
 {    
    int res=0;    
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();    
    String dt=request.getParameter("bday").toString();    
    try    {   
        ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into date1 values(?)");   
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(dt.toString());    
        java.sql.Date mySqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    }  catch(ParseException e)   
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }   
    ps.setDate(1, mySqlDate);    
    res=ps.executeUpdate();   
    if(res!=0)  
    {    
        out.println("<html><body>date inserted</body></html>");  
    }// try catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }//catch out.close();

public void destroy()
{
    try
    {
        con.close();
        ps.close();
    }// try
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// catch
}// destroy
}// class
```

Answer (score 2):

Try formating like this:

```
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dt);
java.sql.Date mySqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```